# How do I make my sculpture pop up when I change it to object mode?

Tags: object-mode, sculpt-mode

I've been recently using Blender and I'm new to the program. I've been following a tutorial on sculpting. I create and object and I'm try to change to object mode. However, when I do It reverts my sculpt back to a sphere. It's not the same thing I've been working on. How do I can which mode I'm in also while allowing it to adjust the same object?

Comment: Hello, a screenshot or two showcasing the problem would be helpful here

Comment: are you using the Multires modifier? In that case, in this modifier, make sure that the Level Viewport is as high as the Sculpt Level. If it's not your problem, maybe show some screenshots or share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: That was it! Thank you so much! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the *Multiresolution* modifier, which creates virtual topology. In this modifier, make sure that the *Level Viewport* is as high as the *Sculpt Level*, otherwise you won't see your sculpting:

[image: multi resolution modifier]